# Kafka: unable to consume events given an offset

Tags: apache-kafka

I was just following the [quick start guide for Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart) and I decided to test offsets a little bit.

The only modification I did to the default configuration was adding:

```
log.retention.minutes=5
```

My `test` topic was created as basic as possible, as suggested in the quick start guide (1 partition, replication factor 1):

```
$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test
```

I've produced some messages, `m1` and `m2` (adding date before and after):

```
$ date
viernes, 21 de julio de 2017, 12:16:06 CEST
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test
>m1
>m2
>^C
$ date
viernes, 21 de julio de 2017, 12:16:25 CEST
```

The thing is I'm able to consume them from the beginning, but I'm not able to consume them given an offset (for instance, offset 0, which I understand points to the first message):

```
$ date
viernes, 21 de julio de 2017, 12:16:29 CEST
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --offset 0 --partition 0
^CProcessed a total of 0 messages
$ date
viernes, 21 de julio de 2017, 12:17:25 CEST
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
m1
m2
^CProcessed a total of 2 messages
$ date
viernes, 21 de julio de 2017, 12:17:50 CEST
```

Most probably I've not understood well this statement from the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/intro#intro_topics):

> In fact, the only metadata retained on a per-consumer basis is the offset or position of that consumer in the log. This offset is controlled by the consumer: normally a consumer will advance its offset linearly as it reads records, but, in fact, since the position is controlled by the consumer it can consume records in any order it likes. For example a consumer can reset to an older offset to reprocess data from the past or skip ahead to the most recent record and start consuming from "now".

Moreover, I've seen that if a produce a third message (`m3`) after running the consumer as described above (i.e. pointing to offset 0), this third message is read:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --offset 0 --partition 0
m3
```

Could anybody explain this behavior, please? Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be, that you set up your topic with more than 1 partitions. So what would happen here is that your messages are round robined (is that a word?) over all available partitions when they are written. If you start a console consumer without specifying a partition and offset, that consumer subscribes to all partitions and thus gets all messages. If you state a partition it will only subscribe to that and thus only get 1/partitioncount of the messages you produce. If you start another consumer at the same time with a different partition number you should see different messages there.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Sönke Liebau. Nevertheless, the topic was set up with only one partition (as the quick start guideline proposes). I'm adding to my question how the topic was created.

Comment: That's quite weird then, I've just tested it out myself using confluent version 3.2.2 and for me it works as expected: https://pastebin.com/VnVH7ZCc

Comment: Oh wait, I indeed made some changes in the server configuration (I was playing with it, but then rollbacked to the default configuration... or what I though it was the default configuration). The thing is I configured `log.retention.minutes=5`. I'll edit my question to reflect this. Apologies for the mesh!

Comment: In that case Kafka probaby deleted the log segment containing messages m1 & m2 between the time you ran the command with --from-beginning and --offset 0. Thus creating the false impression of the offset command not working. If you'd run the first command again my bet would be that you would not receive the first two messages either.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your edit where you added the date commands that show that this is not the case..

Comment: Right, I think I know why this is happening, can't explain yet why exactly though. Please try your experiment again with a newly created topic, that should work. Apparently --offset 0 reverts to "latest", when there is no offset 0 because older messages were already deleted. I'm still looking through the code where exactly this happens to confirm and will then write a proper answer.

Comment: It doesn't revert to "latest" but if any offset has been deleted then if you seek() to that offset and poll() you will get the next highest available offset, which in your case was probably 3. The same is true for compacted topics where there will be missing offsets in the middle of the topics (I.e. 0,1,5,9,13,...). If you seek to 6 and consume you should get 9.

Comment: But shouldn't he have gotten all his messages in that case? They were retrievable with --from-beginning, thus if it reverted to the next larger offset they should have shown up, no?

Answer (score 4):

Alright, after a lot of comments and a bit of code searching I think that this is what is happening:

When you configured your retention period with 5 minutes, you caused Kafka to delete a few of your old messages - most notably the one with the offset 0. So at some point in time the smallest offset in partition 0 became lets say 4.
When you start a console consumer with --from-beginning, it internally [calls a method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L374) that initializes the beginning offset to the smallest offset that can be found in the partition - 4 in this case. With that offset the consumer starts polling and receives that message and all subsequent ones, which is all messages for the partition.

If you start a consumer with --offset 0 that piece of code is bypassed and the consumer polls with an offset of 0 - the broker responds to that with an **OFFSET_OUT_OF_RANGE** error. The Consumer upon receiving that error [resets the offset](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java#L876) for the partition in question, and for this it uses the parameter *auto.offset.reset* which in theory can be *earliest* or *latest*.
However, [due to the way that the *ConsoleConsumer* is written](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/0.11.0.0/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleConsumer.scala#L199), the only way to have this parameter set to *earliest* is, if you pass the command line parameter --from-beginning - which cannot be combined with --offset - so effectively the only possible value that *auto.offset.reset* can have here is: *latest*. 
So what happens when you poll with an offset of 0 that does not exist is an unsuccessful poll for data and after that the same behavior as if you hadn't passed any parameter at all.

Hope that helps and makes sense.

**Update:**

As of Kafka version 1.0 this behavior has been changed by [KAFKA-5629](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5629) and should now behave a bit more in line with expectations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll read it carefully, and I'll come with new doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `--offset earliest`